# Unable to pass prepareGet()

Tags: jdbc, wildfly, vertica

I'm debugging application using WildFly
I'm using Vertica JDBC 07.02.0100

for some reason, I can't pass the following line:

```
    VGet v = myCon.prepareGet(schema,table);
```

If I suspend the application I can see the following:[image]

it looks like infinite loop or something like this. No exception is thrown.
Since I don't have the source code of Vertica I can't debug this.
Did anyone encounter something like this?
What can I do?

**Update**

I updated Vertica driver to 7.2.3 and now I'm getting:
[image]

Comment: `prepareGet` is not a JDBC method, is this part of your code, or a specific method in Vertica?

Comment: Specific method of vertica